# How to check whether getView() is called because of notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a condition in my getView which should only invoke when getView is called because notifyDataSetChanged() is called. The problem is getView can be called because of various reasons like listview layout is changed because of keyboard hide/show, scrolling the list, etc. but in any of these cases, notifyDataSetChanged() method will not be called.

Is there any way in which I can track this?

Thanks

Code

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="250" />
```

Comment: so your code logic is wrong, post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is keep a global variable and create a wrapper method which sets the global variable to true and calls notifydatasetchanged() also. And in your getView() check the value for the global variable for true and do your operations.

Also you will have to set that global variable to false when position in your getView() == yourdatalist.size();

```
    // in the adapter
    boolean notifyDataSetChangedCalled;

    public void notifyDataSetChangedWrapper(){
       notifyDataSetChangedCalled = true;
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    getView(View converView , int position , ViewGroup parent){
       .
       .
       .
       if(position == listItems.size()){
        notifyDataSetChangedCalled = false;
       }
    }
```